# Sharepoint 2016 on-premise User Profile Synchronization and Ad Import

Tags: sharepoint-server

If I have a domain that is trusted with another domain, can i use User Profile Synchronization to sync users in the the Local AD and use AD Import to import users from the trusted domain?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two trust (i think), then you can have sync connect with it. All you have to do is create a separate sync connection with each domain.

also check this for people picker: https://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/01/powershell-for-people-picker-properties/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could perform the sync.

Check this article for more:https://blog.tallan.com/2013/04/18/setting-up-an-external-domain-trust-in-a-simple-sharepoint-2010-extranet-with-separate-ad-domains-and-completing-a-profile-sync/